# Does Bellantoni-Cook safe recursion (or any other implicit characterization of P) admit Kleene's second recursion theorem?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computability, pl.programming-languages

Abstractly, by a *programming language* that operates on binary strings I mean a set $P$ of programs along with a semantics relation $[p](x) = y$, ``the program $p$ on string $x$ halts with output $y$." An *encoding* of a programming language is an identification of $P$ as a subset of binary strings.

Say a programming language with a fixed encoding has the *second recursion property* in case
$$(\forall p \in P)(\exists p^\star \in P)(\forall d \in 2^\star)\ [p](p^\star,d) = [p^\star](d).$$

Now Kleene's second recursion theorem basically says that any reasonable Turing-complete programming language with a reasonable encoding has the second recursion property. My question is:

*Do Bellantoni-Cook safe recursive programs (or any other implicit characterizations of polynomial time), suitably encoded, enjoy the second recursion property?*

**Context.** In the 70's and 80's people figured out that some natural subrecursive programming languages capturing "large" classes (like primitive recursive functions) *did* have the second recursion property. I am wondering whether the same holds for more modern Implicit Computational Complexity-style languages.

**Note.** In classical recursion theory, Kleene's second recursion theorem is equivalent to the Rogers fixpoint theorem. For indexings of complexity classes, that is not the case: the equivalence relies on the existence of universal programs, which do not exist in the subrecursive setting.

Comment: Is this not trivial from completeness?

Comment: what does completeness mean in this sense? (These are not Turing-complete languages)

Comment: Complete for the relevant complexity class, which these systems tend to be.

Comment: Certainly, any polynomial-time computable function can be computed (by definition) by some program in any such language. However, I don't see how the second recursion property trivially follows from this.

Comment: Well, one such program is that which takes as input the code for a turing machine $M$, a polynomial $P$ and an input string $s$, and simulates $M$ for $P(|s|)$ steps on $s$ (the original P-complete problem). Does that fill the requirement?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the original question. What would the program be? (It certainly can't be $p^\star$, which must depend on $p$.)